# Can't send email (smtp)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm doing my homework and I have to send email verification after clicked a button "verify me".

Below is the button and textbox:

[image: button and textbox]

So, the flow is, you have to input your `studentID`, and then system will check the database is your ID exist or not. and if your studentID exist, then we will send confirmation (random password to access the web).

But in here, I have trouble to send the email and honestly, I dont know what is wrong.

Here is my code part (sending mail code only):

```
public void sendingverification()
    {
        //get EMAIL from spesific ID 
        string getEmail = "SELECT Email FROM TableStudent where StudentID = '" + IdTxt.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand sqlcomEmail = new SqlCommand(getEmail, con);

        //get STUDENT FIRST NAME from spesific ID
        string getName = "SELECT StudentFName FROM TableStudent where StudentID = '" + IdTxt.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand sqlcomName = new SqlCommand(getName, con);

        string randomPw = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(10, 5);
        string activationUrl = "http://aws.prominensa.com/izari/web-alumni/login.html";
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("AlumnaeTeam@gmail.com", "S2 Alumnae Team");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(sqlcomEmail.ToString(), sqlcomName.ToString());
        const string fromPassword = "123456";
        const string subject = "Activation Link for S2 Alumnae";
        string body = "Hello " + sqlcomName.ToString() + ", ";
        body += "<br /><br />your account is almost done. You can login with your account now with this link below.";
        body += "<br /><" + activationUrl;
        body += "<br />< Please note that you will be able to login using: ";
        body += "<br />< StudentID = " + IdTxt.Text;
        body += "<br />< Password = " + randomPw;
        body += "<br />< Thank you.";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please 1) Edit your code and write correct C# code? 2) Your ```message``` object seems to be disposed even before you call *Send*, 3) What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the exception or error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Is you are sending email from your gmail, there is some small settings that needs to be done. (I don't remember that setting exactly,If you don't do that you will get an error, just google that you will find what is that).

I see you are using String to build your message, DON'T do that, Instead use StringBuilder.

Check this snippet.

```
            MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
            //verification mail
            mailObj.Subject = "Your Email Subject line";

            mailObj.Body =  ComposeVerficationMailBody(emailDetails.MailMessage, emailDetails.RecipientName);
           emailDetails.SenderName = "Your Website Name";


            mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailObj.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;

            //TO
            mailObj.To.Add(emailDetails.RecipientEmailAddress);
            mailObj.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            mailObj.ReplyToList.Add(emailDetails.ReplyToEmailAddress);
            //From
            mailObj.From = new MailAddress(senderEmailAddress, senderDisplayName);
            using (SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                mailClient.Host = "gmail host";
                mailClient.Port = 587;
                mailClient.EnableSsl = false;
                mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                mailClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                //mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("senderEmail", "senderPassword");


                MailAddress msg = new MailAddress(emailDetails.ReplyToEmailAddress);
                mailClient.Timeout = 500000;
                mailClient.Send(mailObj);



 private String ComposeVerficationMailBody()
 {
    StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();
   //build your message here
   return emailMessage.toString();
 }
```

Hope it suffice your requirement.